# What does XO mean/stand for?

Tags: mass-effect

In the first Mass Effect game, After obtaining the Normady when you leave the Ship's VI says

> XO Presley has the Deck.

and when you return it says

> XO Presley stands relived.

Now i am assuming that since Shepard is the commanding officer Presley is second-in-command who takes command when Shepard is off the ship so when he returns Presley is relived of his command.

From my understanding, it's common that space-operating organizations in Sci-Fi are associated with the Navy (Time Space Administration Bureau's Dimensional Navy in Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha, UNSC Marines in Halo and generally outer-space combat fights refereed to as Marines where Marines are normally under the jurisdiction of the Navy) but i don't think i've heard the term XO refereed to a second-in-command rather normally their rank is used

So what does XO mean? (like how CO = Commanding Officer)

Comment: Google for "XO military" or "XO navy" - Null's link is the very first result

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about military terminology, not something specific to sci-fi

Comment: @HorusKol the question was mainly about the use of XO in Mass Effect, i added the part about the Navy as from my observations Sci-Fi tends to use the Navy as a base command structure for space-operating organizations and thought that XO may not be entirely just Sci-Fi/Mass Effect lingo

Comment: There are many other examples of its use across sci-fi and non-sci-fi works in many different formats (TV, film, book, games) - so I still feel the question is not on-topic here, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XO is a common abbreviation for [Executive Officer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_officer#Military).

Comment: Ahhh, the X is being used in it, when i initially saw Executive Officer i thought it similar to a Chief Executive Officer which is CEO and thought it incorrect to what i was looking for